# Making ExpandableListView respect item margins and padding

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an ExpandableListView that I'm populating with items. I'd like to have the header (here, "meat") be wider than the list items.

[image: Main screen]

However, ExpandableListView doesn't seem to respect margins/padding defined in XML, and also fails to respect programatically-set padding for the items. It does modify the parent ("meat") but the same code doesn't work for the items.

How can I do this?

Here's the relevant part of my custom adapter:

```
 @Override
 public View getGroupView(int position, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_category, null);
    }

    view.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0); //RESPECTED

    initializeGroupComponents(view, getGroup(position));
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int position, int expandedPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_ingredient, parent, false);
    }

    view.setPadding(10, 2, 10, 2); //DOES NOT WORK

    initializeChildComponents(view, getChild(position, expandedPosition));
    return view;
}
```

The relevant portions of my XML:

The group:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_categoryContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

The item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/row"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="62dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take one extra layout for header and add margin

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_categoryContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp">

    //other content
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!